# Facebook lost my account that I used for an iOS game, is there any way to hack the login to retrieve my account back?

Tags: ios, games, facebook

I used to play an iOS game called Battle Camp that was linked though Facebook, and I had an FB account only for that game. I stopped playing for about 3 years and went to start playing again, but because my FB was dormant that long I think it has been deleted. I reached out to the game's developers and they were no help. I then reached out to Facebook and they won't reply to any of my messages. I tried logging in through GameCenter and through email, but neither worked so I guess it was purely through FB. is there anyway possible to get my account back or to hack into my own account?

Comment: start with recovering the FB account at: https://www.facebook.com/login/identify/

Answer (score 1):

You’re at a dead end of the developers won’t release your account tied to validating against Facebook identity.

Unless they have a save file, you wouldn’t be able to reverse engineer it and would have to crack into Facebook or replicate their entire validation system and fool the app to thinking it’s talking to Facebook and is instead talking to your web application and API and you also get past the encryption the developer put in their app to check certificates.

This is all doable, but needs quite advanced skills. For a game, not worth the effort. For a career in security, this would make an excellent paper or project and could get you hired.

Just because your Facebook data is deleted, you could still recover and reactivate the account. I would start to get the account back if you can - https://www.facebook.com/login/identify/